# Laravel - Export PDF with huge data (~10k rows, >80 cols)

Tags: laravel, pdf, export

I'm writing code for feature export report data, I used PhpSpreadsheet with TcfPdf library to export.

But when my data is huge (~10k rows, >80 cols) then output only one blank page.

I tried chunk data and export splitting to multiple files pdf (1.pdf, 2.pdf,...), then merged to one file using pdftk library but still no success.

Additional, if I export multiple columns, pdf did not view all those columns, because paper size of pdf is small.

Does anyone help me? What best solution for export huge data and what library I should use?

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Did you tried this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy ?

Comment: yes, I tried Snappy, but I don't know the solution to apply datatable with snappy, because I want to css like datatable. 
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give a try to [Laravel Snappy PDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)

or my second favorite [DOMPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/)

But for large data I definitely recommend **Laravel Snappy PDF**

Comment: yes, I tried Snappy, but I don't know the solution to apply datatable with snappy, because I want to css like datatable. 
Can you help me?